# Type of Indices supported by Apache Ignite

Tags: indexing, ignite

In the documentation for Apache ignite, it states that they provide indexing functionality for RDDS.

Also in the below link we can find methods to create indices.
http://apacheignite.gridgain.org/docs/sql-queries

Is there any documentation on what kind of indices it supports underneath (B-trees, R-trees)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignite indexes are either based on `SnapTreeMap` [1] or on `ConcurrentSkipListMap`. The former is used for indexes stored in off-heap memory, while the latter is for on-heap.

[1] https://github.com/nbronson/snaptree